# Bash if script is called from terminal echo stdout to terminal, if from cron do not echo output

Tags: bash, cron, io-redirection, stdout

I would like to have a service watchdog script echo the status to the screen if called like ./watchdog.sh but if it is run by cron, there is no need to echo output.  What is the proper method?  Where does stdout go when a script is run under root's crontab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the many cron jobs that I run, I purposely make them so if run on command line appropriate outout is generated but the same script if placed in crontab I always capture both the stdout and stderr to a log file:

`00 12 * * 1-5 /home/aws/bin/myscript.sh >> /home/aswartz/rje/cron.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 4):

Cronjob output is sent to the user via the system's mail system.

You can check whether stdout is a terminal:

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
     echo Terminal
else
     # not a terminal, don't echo
fi
```